# ZSH Prompt printing '[m' instead of '%'

Tags: zsh, prompt

I added a battery function to my vim statusline [here's a link](https://michelerullo.wordpress.com/2018/02/16/hot-to-show-time-and-battery-status-on-vim-8-statusline/). It displays my battery correctly in vim and if I run `$ acpi | grep -oP "(\d+)%"` it returns some number followed by the percent sign (as expected). I decided to update my `zshrc` since it prints better than the `cut` I was using:

```
bat () { acpi | grep -oP "(\d+)%" }
PROMPT="%t | $(bat) | %d
$ "
```

However, what I end up with is:

```
7:22PM | 89[m | /home/rain
$
```

How do I get the `[m` to print as a `%`? Or can I drop it altogether and just have the digit print?

Comment: You appear to have mis-transcribed into the question what you are setting `PROMPT` to.

Comment: What part is appearing as mis-transcribed?

Comment: `%(bat)` does not perform command substitution and does not produce the claimed effect (it rather producing a far more drastic one), so you haven't correctly transcribed the part that does the command substitution.

Comment: Oh. Yes. The `%` should be a `$`. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[m` is probably the tail end of an ANSI escape code `\e[m` (= reset to normal colors & attributes, short form) with the initial ESC character (`\e`) stripped off.

My guess would be that your `grep` is coloring matching strings when run interactively, and the interactivity detection is misfiring when run as part of a shell function whose output becomes part of the prompt.

The percent sign in the output triggers special processing in prompts, and if `%\e` does not mean anything it is simply deleted.

Try defining your `bat` function like this:

```
bat () { acpi | grep --color=never -oP "(\d+)%" }
```

Comment: Alright. So I changed the function to that and the `PROMPT` to `... | $(bat)% | ...` and it looks exactly how I was hoping it would.  Also, that fixed the other problem I was having and now the prompt is all one color. Thanks.